# How to determine possible styling properties for Shiny HTML styling?

Tags: html, css, shiny

I'm trying to figure out HTML styling.

(I'm new to HTML (via shiny in RStudio), so bear with me. )

I get the general setup (i.e., `style = “property:value;”`), but **where/how do I *actually* find the list of possible property names to assign/edit**?

- In other words, how do I know what the potential properties are?

  - Is there a list of them somewhere?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

Comment: @HubertL THANK YOU!! I swear I searched everywhere on w3schools for this -_-.

Comment: Just a note on W3Schools, they are not the best resource out there and are **not** affiliated with the W3C at all. The MDN references in the answer below are regarded a lot better. Further reading: http://www.w3fools.com/ . Thye aren't as bad as they used to be though.

Comment: Also a good IDE/Web Editor will help you out with good code completion and property suggestions. Don't rely on any one thing though.

Answer (score 4):

Quality + thoughtful markup is key to writing sensible style rules.

Ensure you write semantic markup - and you'll have much better time targeting the elements with CSS. These are two lists of EVERYTHING. : )

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

I should also add: https://caniuse.com to cross reference browser support of any given newfangled css property.